# Elasticsearch service running on minikube cluster not reachable from within the cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, minikube, kompose

I am using ***kompose*** to deploy this docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: config/docker/dev/Dockerfile-dev
    container_name: myWebApp-dev
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec","sleep 1000"]
    image: 'localhost:5002/webapp:1'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
    labels:
      kompose.image-pull-policy: 'IfNotPresent'
      kompose.service.type: nodeport
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec","sleep 1000"]
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    container_name: es02
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec","sleep 1000"]
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

to minikube.
The elasticsearch pod and service are running. However, the webapp cannot access the elasticsearch cluster as I get a **connection refused** error when curling from within the webapp pod -> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.108.5.31 port 9200: Connection refused. Does anyone know what the reason for this problem is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In `elasticsearch` section, you have a shell command to `sleep`. And, never started any elasticsearch instances after that.

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec","sleep 1000"]
```

So, looks like, there is no elasticsearch running inside the container and that's why `connection refused` is happening.

**To Fix:**

Get rid of `command:` of `elasticsearch` and `es02`, that way, default `command` will be used.

**Note:**

Now, When the elasticsearch starts, You will face two error (described below) with this compose yaml in kubernetes. These are unrelated to this post, But I will try to giving you direction where to look.

```
ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: memory locking requested for elasticsearch process but memory is not locked
[2]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

Here,

1. you need to [update host system](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode) for `vm.max_map_count`. Exec into minikube virtualbox by `minikube ssh` and run `sudo -s sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144` to change the map_count of host kernel. It will work, because **docker/container doesn't provide kernel level isolation**.

For minikube,

```
minikube ssh 'sudo -s sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144'
```

2. ulimit is not available in `kompose`. [See issue here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kompose/issues/442). So either you have to get rid of both, `bootstrap.memory_lock=true` from `environment:` sections, or you may need to update the docker image. This question is already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123756/how-to-disable-swapping-in-elasticsearch-on-kubernetes) in stackoverflow.

So the improved kompose yaml (works well on minikube):

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ../../../
      dockerfile: config/docker/dev/Dockerfile-dev
    container_name: myWebApp-dev
    command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec","sleep 1000"]
    image: 'localhost:5002/webapp:1'
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
    labels:
      kompose.image-pull-policy: 'IfNotPresent'
      kompose.service.type: nodeport
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    links:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - esdata01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.0.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=elasticsearch,es02
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    volumes:
      - esdata02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

However, I would suggest to follow the elasticsearch [official doc](https://www.elastic.co/elasticsearch-kubernetes) instead of using compose to install elasticsearch in kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I put the command: ["/bin/sh", "-ec","sleep 1000"] is that if I don't put it, I get an "CrashLoopBackoff" error which I have made out to be due to the pod shutting down immediately after the container is created.

Comment: @PaulRousseau, I have updated my answer. You are maybe seeing error because of `note 1 & 2` I described. Look into pod logs to see the error for what it is restarting.

Comment: hi, [Paul Rousseau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5583866/paul-rousseau). Please share with information if you managed to resolve this issue?