# Elasticsearch kubernetes memory lock

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am running an Elastic cluster on Kubernetes, according to the Elastic documentation, memory lock needs to be set to true in order to disable swapping and increase performance.

How ever, when setting this value to true, my pod fails to start up with the following error:

```
This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out.
Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK, soft limit: 83968000, hard limit: 83968000
These can be adjusted by modifying /etc/security/limits.conf, for example:
# allow user 'elasticsearch' mlockall
elasticsearch soft memlock unlimited
elasticsearch hard memlock unlimited
```

How would I change these settings if my elastic image is deployed to Kubernetes?

Comment: Could you check [this](https://timonweb.com/misc/elasticsearch-fails-with-error-this-can-result-in-part-of-the-jvm-being-swapped-out-increase-rlimit_memlock-ulimit-what-to-do/) solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52123756/how-to-disable-swapping-in-elasticsearch-on-kubernetes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by the use of custom entry point to the image.

You will first need to create a custom elastic image based off the official elastic image,

The custom entry point will then change the memory limits, looking something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set memlock limit
ulimit -u unlimited

# Call original entrypoint script
exec /docker-entrypoint.sh "${@}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This my solution for elasticsearch in on-promise Kubernetes :

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: init-limit
          image: busybox:1.27.2
          command:
            [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              "ulimit -Hl unlimited && ulimit -Sl unlimited && ulimit -n 65536 && id",
            ]
          securityContext:
            runAsNonRoot: false
            runAsUser: 0
            capabilities:
              add: ["IPC_LOCK", "SYS_RESOURCE"]
        - name: init-chown
          image: busybox:1.27.2
          command:
            [
              "sh",
              "-c",
              'chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data && echo "done"',
            ]
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: elastic-data-volume
      containers:
        # container elasticsearch
        - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.7.0
          name: elasticsearch
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9200
            - containerPort: 9300
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          env:
            - name: http.host
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: transport.host
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: network.bind_host
              value: "0.0.0.0"
            - name: xpack.security.enabled
              value: "false"
            - name: xpack.monitoring.enabled
              value: "false"
            - name: cluster.name
              value: elasticsearch
            - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
              value: "true"
            - name: discovery.type
              value: "single-node"
            - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m"
            - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
              value: unlimited
            - name: LimitMEMLOCK
              value: infinity
            - name: UsePAM
              value: "yes"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
              name: elastic-data-volume
```

> PS: You must add `Service`, `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim`

Hope this can help some one!